# Read AppSettings from MEF plugin

Tags: c#, app-config, mef, configurationmanager

I would like to access the values in the `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` object from a MEF plugin which has its own `app.config` file.

However, the keys from the `app.config` file are not present in `AppSettings` after the plugin is loaded.
The keys from the application loading the plugin are still present.

I noticed that using a `Settings.settings` file allows this behaviour, via the `app.config` file, so the file must be being loaded somehow.

My plugin looks like:

```
[Export(IPlugin)]
public class Plugin
{
    public Plugin()
    {
        // reads successfully from app.config via Settings object
        var value1 = Settings.Default["Key1"];

        // returns null from app.config via ConfigurationManager
        var value1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key2"]
    }
}
```

The `app.config` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="..." >
      <section name="Plugin.Settings" type="..." />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="Key2" value="Fails" />
  </appSettings>

  <applicationSettings>
    <Plugin.Settings>
      <setting name="Key1" serializeAs="String">
        <value>Works</value>
      </setting>
    </Plugin.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

I can manually load the `app.config` file with:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("Plugin.dll");
var value = AppSettings.Settings["Key2"].Value
```

but this seems more like a workaround than a solution.

Is there a way to access a MEF plugin's `<appSettings>` directly, from inside the plugin? 
If not, what is recommended?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default the ConfigurationManager loads the .config for the entry assembly, i.e. the assembly that started the currently executing process.

The correct way to do this would be something like this:

```
[Export(IPlugin)]
public class Plugin
{
    public Plugin()
    {
        var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        var value = config.AppSettings.Settings["Key2"].Value;
    }
}
```

This would make the plugin automatically open the .config for the DLL it was compiled in, and fetch values from there.

Comment: I see. Could this be what is happening 'behind-the-scenes' when I make the call to `Settings.Default`?

Comment: Maybe. I'm not sure, but Reflector can most certainly shed some light on that.

Comment: Didn't learn much from Reflector, it gets pretty complicated... But the `GetExecutingAssembly()` call is much more preferable to hard-coding the DLL name. Looks like I'll go with this technique.

Comment: I agree. I think it's also a lot better than relying on the auto-generated Settings.settings stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you to use a dependency injection tool like Unity, in order to provide to your plug-ins the configuration they required. By proceeding in this way, your plug-ins will no longer need to reference System.Configuration.dll.

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot use Unity for this current project, but it certainly looks like something to use for future projects.